# C++ template "deferred instantiation"

Tags: c++, templates

What is meant with "deferred instantiation" in C++ templates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deferred instantiation is when the template is not instantiated until the corresponding entity is used for the first time. For example, you have a templated function:

```
template<int Size>
void YourFunction()
{
    //does something
}
```

parameter `Size` can have any possible value that `int` can have. Do you automatically have the templated function instantiated for all possible values of `Size`? No, the template is only instantiated for the values that are actually used as the parameter when the function call first appears in the code:

```
YourFunction<100>(); //instantiated for 100
```

Comment: The reason why this is important: imagine a line `const int number = 100 / Size;`. It shouldn't generate an error until someone tries to  use `YourFunction<0>`.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, that too. But also imagine the compiler would try to instantiate that function for every possible value of `int` - that would be a lot of intermediate data.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the implementation of generics in other languages, it's feasible. You effectively instantiate a single ensemble, not all possible combinations.

Answer (score 4):

I have only heard people use the term "deferred instantiation" to refer to the situation where a class member definition is instantiated only if it is used

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  void f() {
    T a; // invalid if T is void
  }
};

A<void> a; // valid!
```

In this case, `A<void>` is implicitly instantiated because the compiler needs to know its size (formally, the class type needs to be complete, so an instantiation is triggered). But the instantiation of its *member definitions* are *deferred* until they are actually used. This does not only apply to member functions, but also to static data members and nested classes

```
struct Print {
  Print() { std::cout << "hello!"; }
};

template<typename T>
struct A {
  static Print print;
};

template<typename T>
Print A<T>::print;
```

Now even if you implicitly instantiate `A<T>` the message won't be printed until you explicitly refer to `A<T>::print` and *use* it. Explicit instantiation won't defer instantiation of member definitions - so the following will always print the message

```
template struct A<void>;
```

There is a trick to trigger instantiation of member definitions for implicit instantiations though: Refer to them in declaration parts of a class' member, like in the following changed class template

```
template<typename T, T&> struct useit { };

template<typename T>
struct A {
  static Print print;
  typedef useit<Print, print> useit_type;
};
```

Now if `A<T>` is implicitly instantiated the message is printed, because the typedef declaration refers to it.