# CRTP with dependent type, type name lookup

Tags: c++, crtp, dependent-type

There are many discussion about how nested type in derived class should not be used in CRTP. However, some of the cases below actually work fine:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
 public:
  int value = T().value;
};

template <class T>
class B {
 public:

  // case 1: ok, as long as class C does not instantiate;
  class C : public T::I {};

  // case 2: bad, class C instantiated;
  // class C : public T::I {};
  // C c;

  // case 3: bad,
  // typedef typename T::I TI;

  // case 4: bad, similarly, even T::I is used as template parameter
  // typedef Base<typename T::I> BaseTI;

  // case 5: if used as function parameter type, make a trivial template 
  template <typename R, 
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, typename R>::type>>>
  auto get(R n) { return n; }
};

class D : public B<D> {
 public:
  class I {
   public:
    int value;
  };
  I i;
};
```

I'm thinking that how 2, 3, 4 was failing is due to compiler's 2-phase name look up; I can also reason that case 5 is okay because only when `B::<T>::get<R>` is called it's getting resolved. However, I don't understand why case 1 runs fine, especially that given 2 does not compile.

Why 1, and 2 differs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your compiler sees `class D : public B<D>`, it tries to instantiate `B<D>`. At this point, `D` is still an incomplete type and `I` is not known yet. However due to "deferred instantiation" the nested class is not instantiated until its first use. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3691176/8359552):

> ...instantiation of its member definitions are deferred until they are actually used. This does not only apply to member functions, but also to static data members and **nested classes**.

Therefore case 2 fails but case 1 works just fine. From the referred answer, you can also see that a typedefs are not deferred and therefore, `D` is incomplete when you declare them.

Comment: tried the static data case. However, `const static int i = T::I().value;` or `const static typename T::I ti;` still gives the same error ` error: no member named 'I' in 'D'`; looks like even if the static data is instantiated; it's type was looked up?

Comment: I think I might get a sense now: it only refers to the static `variable` instantiation being deferred, but not it's type (and hence type lookup); similarly, for member functions, it's definition is not checked (so that T::I can appear in a function definition body, but not in its signature)l However, I am not entirely understanding, why for nested class, `class C : public T::I`, which declares `C` as derived from `T::I`, `T::I` was not checked/looked up?

Comment: @dragonxlwang I am also not an expert on this, but I think the ```public T::I``` part already belongs to the class definition (just think of how you would forward declare a class). Like for functions, only the declaration is checked but the check of definition part is deferred. Can someone else confirm this? Or am I on the wrong track?